# Latest tweet from multiple users on same page?

Tags: jquery, tweets

Is there a way to display the latest tweets from four users on the same page? I'm currently using the code from [Sea of Clouds](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/) to display the latest tweet from one user and it works excellently. I'm wondering if maybe I can tweak that somehow to display the latest tweet for more than one user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this line from the source: jquery.tweet.js, line 129.

```
var query = (s.query || 'from:'+s.username.join(' OR from:'));
```

It seems that s.username is an array and that you can populate it with multiple user names i.e. s.username = [user1, user2, user3] etc. Leave the query falsy if you do this. Good luck :)